# dp и dip в values/dimens

Tags: android

В чем разница между:

1. `<dimen name="top_margin">4.0dip</dimen>`

и

2. `<dimen name="top_margin">4dp</dimen>`

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Нет никакой разницы. Это абсолютно равнозначные величины.

dp = dip - density independent pixels, независимые от плотности пиксели. Абстрактная единица измерения, основанная на физической плотности экрана с разрешением 160 dp.

При плотности экрана 160dpi 1dp = 1пикселю.